# How can I put another text box in the same row as my other text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, alignment, row

I managed to make my zip textbox aligned with my delivery text box. This is the code.

```
<div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="227px" Height="81px"
                                        name="form-first-name" placeholder="Delivery Address..." class="form-first-name form-control" Text-Mode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Delivery Address is required." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" 
                                        ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator10" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Enter a valid Address" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" 
                                        ForeColor="Red" 
                                        ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z# .0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </div>
```

But it has no space between the 2 textboxes? How can I do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "float: left" property to your two textboxes. It makes it align on same line and use css for doing the styling.

Example code is shown below. Just add an id for two divs and give some unique id.

```
HTML

ABC<br />
<div id="textbox1"></div>
<div id="textbox2"></div>

CSS

#textbox1, #textbox2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;    
    width: 100px;    
    height: 100px;    
}

#textbox1 {
    background-color: red;
}

#textbox2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/H499e/)

Comment: do i have to make a css file? or it can be inside a <style>? thanks

Comment: If you application is large you can make separate css style so that a single style sheet can reference all the pages. For small applications you can put it inside a style.

Comment: understood. btw can i not add a css style and directly put it beside my other textbox? is there any other trick?

Comment: Its depends but simply you can use &nbsp;  between those two textboxes for setting the space between them

Comment: You can also use css margins to set spaces like                #textbox/*texbox id*/

{

margin-left:20px;/*change the px as per your need*/

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use server side text box, then just put both textbox together.
Remove class from text box and just place both textbox with each other.
let me know if you have any query.

Comment: thank you for the response. pls see my updated query sir. i managed to put it together but there is no space between them

Answer (score 0):

So if you already got them side by side, you can add some margin-left (or padding-left) to the CSS on the right box. You could add margin-right (or padding-right) to the left box CSS.

Answer (score 0):

simply create a table with 3 columns + one row and put your textboxes  inside seperately.

Here;

```
      <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td style="width: 3px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i added this code on top

```
<style>
#txtAddress
{
    margin-right:75px;
}
```

and my 2 textboxes, i added float:left

```
 <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="227px" Height="81px" 
                                        name="form-first-name" placeholder="Delivery Address..." class="form-first-name form-control" Text-Mode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Delivery Address is required." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" 
                                        ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator10" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Enter a valid Address" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" 
                                        ForeColor="Red" 
                                        ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z# .0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" name="form-zip-code" MaxLength="4" Width="200" placeholder="Zip Code..." class="form-zip-code form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Zip code is required." ControlToValidate="txtZip" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Enter a valid zip code" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtZip" 
                                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=^[0-9]*$></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </div>
```